# Rails 4 params validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

User create a post and assign it to one of his collections (post belongs_to collection)

I have a working dropdown that read collection_id from current user, however, I'd like to  avoid user(attacker) pass wrong parameters like collection_id belongs to incorrect user.

I tested using a text_field and assign collection_id from incorrect user and post saved, that is what I want to prevent.

How can I do that?

1) Within business layer. (I guess inside model validation)

2) Within db layer (some db constrains)

3) Preferable both

**Note: I need to pre-fill form with some variables from previous step, then user can change or fill in case they are empty**

post_controller.rb:

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(url: @url, content: @title)

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, :url, :collection_id)
end
```

Models:

```
collection.rb:
belongs_to :user
has_many   :posts

user.rb:
has_many :posts
has_many :collections

post.rb:
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :collection
```

routes:

```
post   'post'    => 'posts#create'
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@post, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :url %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%#= f.text_field :collection_id %> # This to test passing incorrect values
    <%= f.collection_select :collection_id, Collection.order(:id),:id,:title, include_blank: true %>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The values from the form go to post_controller#create

Comment: Where is `post_params`, and more specifically, the result from your `collection_select` being used in your controller?

Comment: the result from your collection_select go to  post_controller#create

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have established the association between a user and his/her collections, maybe you can try:

```
unless current_user.collections.find(params[:post][:collection_id]).blank?
    @post = current_user.posts.build(url: @url, content: @title)
end
```

It  will check if the collection belongs to the user. In case such a collection does not exist, it will return nil.

Another thing that you can try if the collection is associated with the user is:

```
current_user.collections.find(params[:post][:collection_id]).posts.build(url: @url, content: @title)
```

I am not entirely sure if these are the most efficient ways myself, but I guess they should do the job that you are looking to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can avoid saving wrong record by checking if `collection_id` belongs to user or not by doing like :

```
unless current_user.collection_ids.include?(params[:post][:collection_id]).blank?
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
end
```

But I think you should restrict with user specific collection ids to select from like :

```
<%= f.collection_select :collection_id, current_user.collections.order(:id),:id,:title, include_blank: true %>
```